# Implementing type converter for specific type dropdown items

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter

The usercontrol that will use the type converter

```
Public Class MYControl : Usercotrol 
{

private ListItem _Language;
[TypeConverter(typeof(LanguageEditor))]
public ListItem Language
    {
        get
        {
            return _Language;
        }
        set
        {
            _Language= value;
        }
    }
}
```

The type to list in the dropdown property window

```
public class ListItem
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }
    private string _Value;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
        }
    }
    public ListItem(string Name, string value)
    {
        _Value = value;
        _Name = Name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._Name;
    }
}
```

How do i implement the type converter for this, this is what i tried without success

```
public class LangEditor : TypeConverter
{
    private ArrayList values;

    public LangEditor()
    {
        // Initializes the standard values list with defaults.
        values = new ArrayList();
        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))

            values.Add(new ListItem(ci.DisplayName, ci.Name));
    } // New

    // Indicates this type converter provides a list of standard values.
    public new override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    } // GetStandardValuesSupported

    // Returns a StandardValuesCollection of standard value objects.
    public new override System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // Passes the local value array.
        StandardValuesCollection svc = new StandardValuesCollection(values);
        return svc;
    } 

    public new override bool CanConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type sourceType)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as ListItem;
        return propItem != null && TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ListItem)).CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    } // CanConvertFrom

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var propItem = context.Instance as ListItem;

        if (propItem != null)
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ListItem)).ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        else
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value, ListItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, `Language` is a `ListItem`. What are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: The designer is going to use the ToString override to get the text which happens to be DisplayName.  But it will never send back a ListItem, just that string and you dont handle that.

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 yes, this is the problem, what is the fix for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to some syntax and compiler errors the main issue, as mentioned in a comment, is that your `ConvertFrom` method expects to get back a `ListItem`.  Even though that is what you provide in the `StandardValuesCollection`, the designer has no idea about your Type.

The designer needs a string for the drop down list, and in this case will use your `ToString()` method.  But you are going to get back that string to convert/rehydrate.

You also probably want to decorate your **`Type`** with the `TypeConverter` attribute if you want it associated with all uses of it.  Decorating only the `UserControl` property means just that usage has a converter.  It makes it hard to debug.

I also used an idiomatic name for the converter.

```
//Public Class MYControl : Usercotrol 
public class MYControl : UserControl 
{
    public ListItem Language {get; set;}
}

// Associate the TypeConverter with the Type, not property
[TypeConverter(typeof(ListItemConverter))]
public class ListItem
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}

    // serialization will need this
    public ListItem()
    { }

    public ListItem(string name, string value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

The main problem is in `Can/ConvertFrom`:

```
 var propItem = context.Instance as ListItem;
 if (propItem != null)
      ...
```

The designer uses the names (strings) for the drop down and `string`, the user picks a string and that is what you will get back to convert, never a `ListItem`.

The converter should also override `GetStandardValuesExclusive` - users cannot make up or type in a new language, those supplied are the only legal ones, no?

Other changes in the `TypeConverter` code include:

- Using a `List` and not `ArrayList` which is obsolete
- Remove `new` from the overrides so it will compile
- The `StandardValuesCollection` just needs to be a string collection, so I changed it to get the names from the list.

---

```
public class ListItemConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private List<ListItem> languages;

    public ListItemConverter()
    {
        // Initializes the standard values list with defaults.
        languages = new List<ListItem>();

        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
        {
            languages.Add(new ListItem(ci.DisplayName, ci.Name));
        }
    } 

    // Indicates this type converter provides a list of standard values.
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    } 

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // Passes the local array.
        StandardValuesCollection svc = new StandardValuesCollection(languages);
        return svc;
    } 

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                          System.Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            // where the debug code goes
            return true;
        }
        else
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    } 

    // ADDED: the list is exclusive - no new entries allowed
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if(value is string)
        {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)languages.
                        FirstOrDefault( q => (string.Compare(q.Name, value.ToString(),true) == 0));
            return item;
        }
        else
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

In `ConvertFrom`, you simply need to look up the display name you get back, find the related ListItem in the collection and return it.  `FirstOrDefault` ought never fail and return the Default (null) since you are working from an **exclusive** `StandardValuesCollection`.

Comment: `users cannot make up or type in a new language?` No