# Localizing Dropdowns in a PropertyGrid

Tags: dropdown, propertygrid

I hate admitting when I get stuck, but I'm stuck. I have done a few `PropertyGrids` for settings, but on a recent personal project I decided that everything in a test application should be localized. Broadly speaking, this is easy. Thanks to stackoverflow, I was able to create sub-classes that let me make attributes for fields/properties that correctly display text in the user's preferred language. However, in the same PropertyGrid, the actual language selection is a problem.

Let me present the concept as a key-value pair:

- en = English
- en-GB = British English
- es = Spanish
- th = Thai

In my settings in a dropdown I want to show just "English", "Spanish", etc., not the language codes. If the interface language was Spanish, I should get these language pairs:

- en = Íngles (EE.UU.)
- en-GB = Íngles del Reino Unido
- es = Español
- th = Tailandés

In so many other situations, accomplishing this is fairly easy. For example, on a web page, I can generate a drop-down with presentation text in any language, but can assign an ID selection that has nothing to do with the presentation text. Simple. But I need to do this in a `PropertyGrid`.  So let me get to the code:

```
            [TypeConverter(typeof(LangStringConverter))]
            public string Language { get; set; }
```

I throw that on top of the property. In the LangStringConverter class I add the following as an exercise:

```
            public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            {
                List<String> list = new List<String>();
                list.Add("en");
                list.Add("en-GB");
                list.Add("es");
                list.Add("th");
                return new StandardValuesCollection(list);
            }
```

If I do nothing else, I can later save the values to my configuration file after grabbing from the `PropertyGrid`. It makes a great computer geek interface. Sadly, users must be taken in to account; I can't show "es" when I should be showing "Spanish." I can cure the display as follows:

```
            public override object convertfrom(itypedescriptorcontext context, cultureinfo culture, object value)
            {
                var label = resources.resourcemanager.getstring($"lang_{value.tostring()}");
                return label;
            }
```

This works. However, later, when I go to process the information in the following manner:

```
        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SettingValue sv = (SettingValue)(OptionsGrid.SelectedObject);
            Settings.Default.Language = sv.Language;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            Close();
        }
```

The value in `sv.Language` is the display text, not the code. I suppose I could hunt through the resources for a text match in the wrong direction, but I spent hours today looking at the most gawdawful PHP code that did everything the hard way. I can't go down a similar path with this. How do I display "English", "Spanish" etc. in the PropertyGrid and yet get "en", "es", etc. as a result to store in settings?

Comment: What you can do instead is use a non string type (like "MyCulture", etc.) and use the TypeConverted to translate this class instance into and from strings

Comment: Thanks for tip. I tried it, but it doesn't quite work. Explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254157/implementing-type-converter-for-specific-type-dropdown-items. Fortunately, labels for the codes are as unique as the labels, so, as I mentioned, I can always work backwards. It'll be just my luck that in some language out there, "English" and "Russian" are spelled the same.